# Shortcode Display From Wordpress Dashboard Page Without Using post_id

Tags: php, themes, shortcode

I have this code for showing recent posts on my home page custom theme and it works well.

functions.php code:

```
function my_recent_posts_shortcode($atts){
    $q = new WP_Query(
        array( 'orderby' => 'date','posts_per_page' => '4')
    );
    $list = "";

    while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();    
        echo '<div class="item">';

        $title=get_the_title();

        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {    
            echo '<a class="single-image link-icon" href="'.get_permalink().'">';

            $list .=the_post_thumbnail(array(300,200),array('alt' =>$title));   

            echo '</a>';   
        }

        echo '<h6 class="title"><a href="'.get_permalink().'"><span>'.$title.'</span></a></h6>';  
        echo '<div class="entry-body">';

        $list .= wpe_excerpt('wpe_excerptlength_index', '');

        echo '<a class="button default color" href="'.get_permalink().'">Read More</a>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';

        endwhile;

        return $list;
}

add_shortcode('recent-posts', 'my_recent_posts_shortcode');
```

This is the shortcode I use on my pages->Home page

> [recent-posts]

For displaying the shortcode I have to use:

```
<?php
$post_id = 1746;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$check=$queried_post->post_content;
echo do_shortcode($check);
?>
```

For displaying the shortcode, I used $post_id of my home page. I want to display the shortcode content without using post_id. When I use the shorcode on my homepage, it automatically calls that shorcode and displays the result. My theme URL is http://templategraphy.com/wp-demo/businessguru/

Please suggest some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_the_ID(); function in place of $post_id= 'your post id' so that you don't have to place the post id manually every time. The [Function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) automatically gets the id of the post/page